# When a left column has fixed width, how can I make a right column take up the whole of the remaining space and then centre text within it?

Tags: html, css

When a left column is of fixed width, how can I make a right column take up the whole of the remaining space and then centre an element within it?

This is what I've got so far. It's creating a right column that is only as wide as the text, and sending the column over to the right of the parent element.

```css
#left-col {
  width: 250px;
  float: left;
}
#right-col {
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
}
#right-col-element {
  color: #f00;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="left-col">
</div>
<div id="right-col">
  <div id="right-col-element">text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It isn't right justifying the text. When you float an element, it will only be as big as the contents inside of it. And if the  contents is just a single word, then the column is only as wide as the word. The text is centered, it just doesn't look that way because the column is only as wide as the word. If you want to see that it's centered, give the column a width that exceeds the word. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WROXKz

Comment: Thanks @GCyrillus for teaching me how to post a code snippet! I will do this in future.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelCoker. I will rephrase the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can do this is by setting the margin-left property of your right-col element to match the width of the left-col element.

```
#left-col {
  width: 250px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#right-col {
  margin-left:250px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

See fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/e3kbhfo1/

Comment: Thanks. That does the job, and very cleanly. But I needed to add "width:auto" to #right-col in the browser I'm using, FF50.

Answer (score 0):

You can use position absolute and set the top and left:

```css
#left-col {
  width: 250px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 200px;
}
#right-col {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  height: auto;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="left-col">
  left left left
</div>
<div id="right-col">
  <div>text
     <span>span</span>
  <div>last one</div>
  </div>
 
</div>
```

And a couple of hints:

1. use classes instead of id's.
2. always set height when you want to test the centre aligned items vertically
3. always set width if you are doing the same horizentally

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't quite what I want. With this code, when I narrow the screen width the text in the right column goes on top of what's in the left column. And please can you explain point 1? My left column and right column here are one-off elements with different styles. I learnt that ids were right for such elements.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using flexbox and assign `flex-grow` to the element you want to take up the available space.

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}
#left-col {
  width: 100px;  
  background: #ccc;
}
#right-col {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<div id="left-col">
</div>
<div id="right-col">
  <div id="right-col-element">text</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Flexbox

You can set `flex: 1;` for fluid element and not to shrink.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.fixed {
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.fluid {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="fixed">
    Fixed
  </div>

  <div class="fluid">
    Fluid
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Old style: using `overflow: hidden;`

Besides flex solution you can use `overflow: hidden` for fluid element to take remaining space:

```css
.fixed {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.fluid {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
  Fixed
</div>

<div class="fluid">
  Fluid
</div>
```

#### Old style: `display: table-cell;`

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.fixed {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.fluid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="fixed">
   Fixed
  </div>

  <div class="fluid">
   Fluid
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Using "overflow: hidden" is very neat.